# Water entering basement, can regrading help in my situation?

Tags: basement, foundation, grading

I have attached the plan for my property. To the left is the plan of the basement and the right is the plan for the ground level. The 4 black arrows indicate where i am seeing water ingress whenever it rains heavily (ref image on the left)

The grading of the land around the property is shown by the red arrows. Because of the shape of the house, the land is graded towards the rear of the building. The patches in grey have concrete pavers with polymeric sand between them. The downspouts are shown as yellow circles and are connected to solid PVC 4" piping that takes the water away from the building.

An additional complication is that on the pic to the left there are a couple of shaded areas marked as existing crawl space. The footings for these crawl spaces do not go all the way down to the foundation footings. The deck shown in the image to the right is built on a concrete form/box and has footings at about a foot deep. Any rainwater falling on it goes straight through.

Additionally, in the pic to the left, there is an egress window well shown in brown. It is about 3' deep and it has a drain connection which removes all water falling in it to the city storm water line. However, it has a boundary/lip protrudes over the grade by 6". There is a slight water ingress about 2-3 feet away from it in the basement.

Edit: There are two sump pumps in the basement, indicated by green dots. Water is flowing down from the walls where the black arrows are and not coming up from the ground. The water in the sump pit is about a foot below the floor.

I am most concerned about the water coming in from the back of the basement. The entire basement is finished so it is not possible to see the walls. The foundation is rather old and is not a poured foundation. Can regrading the land away from the back out the house help keep water out? What else can be done in this case?[image]

Comment: Yes, regarding can help, and should usually be the first thing tried since it's cheap and easy. Making sure rain gutters don't dump the water right at the foundation also helps.

If that doesn't do the job, or if you want more detailed advice, see the many past questions about wet basements.

Comment: If I understand, you’ve got a drain pipe sticking up too high in the window well. Either cut it down or perforate it. (Landscape cloth wrapped around will help avoid clogging.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate i could have worded that better. I meant to say that the brown box is the egress window well, it is about 3' deep and has a drain inside it. the well has a wall/lip that sticks 6" above the grade.

Comment: The only way to tell if grading would help is to do it.  Only when you've done everything possible at the surface can you start to imagine a generally high water table all around your house and do what you must do about that.

Comment: I see... ignore that comment, then. Other thing to think of after regrading would be a french drain to the left of the master br.

Comment: @jay613 does it make sense to pour concrete all around. Most houses in my street dont have any exposed dirt. They all have concrete surfaces with some having asphalt on top for added measure.

Comment: I doubt a concrete apron around your house would have much impact.  If water is entering at all the black arrows, you must have drenched soil all around your house.  If the water is coming from the surface the concrete might delay it slightly, but the ground will still end up soaked.  You want to ensure all water is diverted far enough away that it subsequently flows away from your house.  A HUGE concrete apron might do that (or might still fail), but there are better ways that are more economical and attractive.  And it would be a terrible shame to do that and find out it's not surface water.

Comment: @jay613 you are absolutely spot on. I have never seen the ground dry out fully. I want to say I am almost 100% certain that it is surface water that is soaking through. I have a sump pump right where some of the water comes in (left pic, green dot next to the first black arrow). This sump pump runs rather infrequently even when it is raining. The water in the sump is about a foot below the floor.

Comment: @jay613 what other methods would you recommend to move the water away. I did a walk around of my neighborhood and some places have a large concrete apron with a drain on them.

Comment: Wait.  You have a sump pump?  Forgive me for assuming you did not but that seems an important thing to mention.  Normally a sump pump is part of a system that includes a perimeter drain system.   So if you have THAT, your question needs to be much more specific about what is wet *that should not be wet*.   You expect the perimeter drains and the sump pit to be wet, and they protect the interior.  Is that not working as expected?  Its running "infrequently" is at odds with your problem description.  Please treat this more explicitly in the question.

Comment: @jay613 Let me clarify, the sump pump is working perfectly. The pit is wet and has some standing water always. When the pump runs, I can see water flow into the pit from behind the sump liner. There is an interior perimeter drain that feeds into the sump. The perimeter drains are moist indicating that water is flowing through them into the sump. The switch is set at 10" from the base of the pump, whenever this threshold is hit, the pump operates.

Comment: @jay613 what is wet is the walls (where the arrows are). Water is flowing into the basement from behind the walls. The cracks on the wall(s) are not visible as there is sprayfoam insulation and drywall up.

Comment: Ok so your basement is dry, your floor is dry, you have a working sump system, your only objective is to eliminate dampness from the walls?    THAT should be your question.  And it has probably been answered thoroughly elsewhere.

Comment: @jay613 its not just dampness, there is water that is leaking out from the wall. The last time it rained there was about a couple of gallons that I mopped up.